# python, beautifulsoup) if Statement doesn't work

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to parse an URL and text with this source:

```
<div class="news_list">
                <a href="/media/view.asp?idx=68230&amp;page=2&amp;kind=2">

                <img src="/media/upFiles2/2018/04/4-82(250).jpg" height="70" alt="" class="news_img">

                <span class="news_txt">영등포구, 7월까지 어린이보호구역 CCTV 환경 개선한다</span>
                </a><br>
                <a href="/media/view.asp?idx=68230&amp;page=2&amp;kind=2">영등포구가 사업비 1억5,000만여원을 투입해 오는 7월까지 어린이보호구역 내 설치된 방범용 CCTV 주변 환경을 개선한다. 구는 환경개선사업을 통해 학교폭력, 유괴 등 각종 범죄와 교통사고로부터 어린이들을 안전하게...</a> <span class="news_writer">박미영 기자 | 2018.04.07 11:38</span>
                </div>
```

there is no specific feature on tag 'a', so i use parent class name.
here is my code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urlopen("http://www.boannews.com/media/t_list.asp?Page=1&kind=" )
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")

for a in soup.find_all("a") :
    print(a.parent.get('class'))
    if a.parent.get('class') == "news_list" :
        print(a.text)
        print(a.get('href'))
```

when i use `print(a.parent.get('class'))` , i can get 'news_list'

but there is no print text or href on if Statement.

i think there seems to be no grammatical error, no mistake. i have no idea which part is wrong.

here's the result of my code

[image: result screen]

Comment: question) there is two 'a' tag. one have text, other have no text. is that important in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a.parent.get('class')` is returning a list (because tags can have many classes), and lists don't equal strings

Flip the if statement to check if the list *contains the class*

```
if "news_list" in a.parent.get('class', []):
```

Answer (score 0):

As the bug in your code has been already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49723027/4796844), I'd like to recommend using [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) instead.

```
for a in soup.select('.news_list > a'):
    print(a.text)
    print(a['href'])
```

Notice the usage of the [`select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of `find_all`.

It's much cleaner than:

```
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    if 'news_list' in a.parent.get('class', []):
        ...
```